# "It's hard to find a good path to taking this mission on". Why "taking"

Tags: grammar, gerunds

So the sentience is "**It's hard to find a good path to taking this mission on**", I wonder why it is "to taking it on" not "to take it on", is "taking" using as a gerund? Can I say "It's hard to find a good path to take this mission on"? What's the difference?

Comment: I'd say, yes, 'taking' is a gerund here. Something (can be replaced with a noun) one struggles to find a good path to.

Comment: The sentence is very poorly constructed and hard to parse.  Only if you consider "taking this mission on" to be the action toward which you're seeking a "path" (ie, means of execution) does it make any sense.  I think most people would interpret the sentence as erroneous and assume that "take" was intended, vs spending the time to parse it "correctly".

Comment: "It's hard to find a good way to approach this mission"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"... find a good path to take this mission on" would describe the physical route you're taking the mission on, like walking a dog, if you delve into it too literally. Otherwise it would describe the path the mission would be taken through, the way the actual mission would be handled.

"... find a good path to taking this mission on" describes the path to how the mission initially be approached; it's more about the action of 'taking on the mission', the acceptance of the mission in the first place.